# How to use App bar to toggle custom widget below the app bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I know that I can give Icons and perform actions when tapped in my app bar but I dont know to toggle the widget just below the app bar.

[image]

I tried Position widget but it didn't work for me.

Would appreciate if Anyone could help me just to toggle the box(dont need help with anything inside the box)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator to get a function like that.

create a bool like

```dart
bool isOpen
```

and show you widget like

```dart
isOpen?YourWidget:null
```

the above code will check if `isOpen` is true.
If it is true, it'll show `YourWidget()`.
else it'll show nothing.

You can use `SetState()` to toggle between these.

To know more about ternary operator and how to use it to conditionally show/hide Flutter widgets, take a look at [Here](https://mukhtharcm.com/dart-ternary-operator/)

Answer (score 0):

Use preferred size widget at the bottom property off app bar

Comment: how can I toggle it? ternary operator?

Comment: Use animated container, first tap height = what you want, another tap height = 0